# sqlite error in database

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

This is my code for connection manager class

```
public class ConnectionFactory {
 Connection con = null;
 Statement stmt = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;
 boolean flag=false;

 //Constructor starts
 public ConnectionFactory(){
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db.sqlite");
        stmt=con.createStatement();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }//end of constructor ConnectionFactory

 //method Connection starts
 public Connection getConnection(){
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db.sqlite");
         System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return con;

 }//end of method Connection

 //method checkLogin starts
 public boolean checkLogin(String username,String password, String user){
    if(user=="ADMINISTRATOR"){
        String query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"+username+"' AND password='"+password+"' AND category='ADMINISTRATOR'";
        try{
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()){
                flag=true;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        String query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"+username+"' AND password='"+password+"'AND category='NORMAL USER'";
        try{
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()){
                flag=true;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return flag;
  }
 }
```

the connection to database is successful. and the login is successful. so its clear that data is accessible from db but still its giving some errors.

these are the errors

```
java.sql.SQLException: database connection closed
at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.checkOpen(CoreConnection.java:336)
at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.createStatement(JDBC4Connection.java:38)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.createStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:193)
at com.inventory.dao.ProductDAO.<init>(ProductDAO.java:37)
at com.inventory.ui.Products.loadDatas(Products.java:421)
at com.inventory.ui.Products.<init>(Products.java:38)
at com.inventory.ui.Dashboard.<init>(Dashboard.java:44)
at com.inventory.ui.LoginDialog.loginBttnMouseClicked(LoginDialog.java:195)
at com.inventory.ui.LoginDialog.access$100(LoginDialog.java:18)
at com.inventory.ui.LoginDialog$2.mouseClicked(LoginDialog.java:68)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.inventory.dao.ProductDAO.getQueryResult(ProductDAO.java:482)
    at com.inventory.ui.Products.loadDatas(Products.java:422)
    at com.inventory.ui.Products.<init>(Products.java:38)
    at com.inventory.ui.Dashboard.<init>(Dashboard.java:44)
    at com.inventory.ui.LoginDialog.loginBttnMouseClicked(LoginDialog.java:195)
    at com.inventory.ui.LoginDialog.access$100(LoginDialog.java:18)
    at com.inventory.ui.LoginDialog$2.mouseClicked(LoginDialog.java:68)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

i have tried most of the options available in online forms. still no help.

Comment: The exceptions look rather self-explanatory. You are trying to use a closed connection. And, you are trying to use a null pointer. Neither of those are considered a best-practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling a connection in your query. Try with this in all your statements

```
 public boolean checkLogin(String username,String password, String user){      
    this.getConnection(); // See your System.out.prinln in the console
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null; 
                if(user=="ADMINISTRATOR"){
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();   
            String query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"+username+"' AND password='"+password+"' AND category='ADMINISTRATOR'";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(s);
                    try{
                        rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
                        while(rs.next()){
                            flag=true;
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        finally {
          stmt.close();
          rs.close();
        }
```

Comment: it actually removed one error but one still remains

Comment: `
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.inventory.database.ConnectionFactory.checkLogin(ConnectionFactory.java:71)
 at com.inventory.ui.LoginDialog.loginBttnMouseClicked(LoginDialog.java:197)
 at com.inventory.ui.LoginDialog.access$100(LoginDialog.java:21)
 at com.inventory.ui.LoginDialog$2.mouseClicked(LoginDialog.java:71)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
`

Comment: MY bad I was calling twice the connection. I edited my answer.

Comment: this is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating connection at two places that is not ideal.

Reusing statement and result set objects is not a good practice.

You are creating connections but tell me where you are closing the created connections. If you try to create connection while you are already having one then there will be high chances of connection exception issues.

So make sure you are having only one DB connection at a time and don't reuse the statement and result set objects.

I suggest to rewrite your getConnection(), checkLogin() methods.

```
//method Connection starts
public Connection getConnection(){
    Connection con = null;

    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db.sqlite");

        System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");
    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return con;
}//end of method Connection

//method checkLogin starts
public boolean checkLogin(String username,String password, String user){

    boolean flag=false;

    try( Connection con = getConnection(); Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); ){
        if(user == "ADMINISTRATOR"){

            String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"+username+"' AND password='"+password+"' AND category='ADMINISTRATOR'";
        }else{

            String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"+username+"' AND password='"+password+"'AND category='NORMAL USER'";
        }

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()){
            flag = true;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: @AnshulSharma remove creating connection in constructer of ConnectionFactory

Comment: nope.. its no use.. i guess there is something else wrong with my code.